# configure https://domainname:3000 in AWS ec2 instances

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

There is a NodeJS application hosted in the AWS EC2 instance. We need to configure HTTPS for the instance of all ports like 3000,1337 and 8080 for Call service through our Android apps.

here We are puzzled to configure https://domainname:3000,https://domainname:1337 and https://domainname:8080. Please suggest to us how we can solve this using Nginx or AWS load balancer.

Comment: You should provide more details, Would you like to run your single NodeJS application on multiple ports with https or multiple NodeJS applications in a single server that can be accessed over https too?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below useful links for  deployed node in AWS

- https://sumantmishra.medium.com/how-to-deploy-node-js-app-on-aws-with-github-db99758294f1
- https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/977/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-application-on-aws-ec2-server
- https://aws.plainenglish.io/deploying-a-nodejs-application-in-aws-ec2-c1618b9b3874

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. we have already installed and hosted the application through AWS. 
But my query is how can I run my application as https://domainname:3000 and others.